# Define the given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ denote spheres of radii $1$ and $100$,respectively. Prove that the points on the surface of $S_1$ and those on the surface of $S_2$ are sets with the same cardinality.

I don't want the answer I just want to know how to represent all those points on $S_1$ and $S_2$, like the set of reals is $(-\infty,\infty)$. So that I can prove a one to one correspondence.

Comment: Well first of all, $(-\infty,\infty)$ is not the set of all rationals, although it is a superset thereof. As for your question, what is a characterizing feature of the points on a sphere of radius $r$?

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for spotting that :D

Comment: $S_1 = \left\{\left(x,y,z\right) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\right\}$

Comment: @MickA and $S_2={x,y,z}:x^2+y^2+z^2=10^2$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MickA this does it to what i am asking but can u provide a hint as to how can i prove a one to one correspondence between s1 and s2.

Comment: If you draw a line from the origin out through both spheres in all possible directions, that will give you a 1-1 relationship. Representing that as a function shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Actually $S_2 = \left\{\left(x,y,z\right) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 100^2\right\}$, as the formula for a sphere has $r^2$ on the right, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RossMillikan ha ha... yes you're right.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks

Comment: @MickA thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Concentric spheres, radial lines.